# class def not found in jboss as 7.X

Tags: java-ee-6, jboss7.x, ear

I have a project structure as

```
eardirectory.Ear
  lib/
    my-custom-classes.jar
    .....
    .....
  my-custom-ejb.jar
  META-INF/
    ....
```

```
//Now I tried to load classes from classloader as
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
clazz = Class.forName(my-custom-classes.class1.class.getName(), true, cl);
```

but this will not work as current thread is of jboss and jboss has not any identification of my-custom-classes.jar.
**So my question is how this can be done with jboss?** I have to have to load class definition at runtime.
Is there any way in **"jboss-deployment-structure"** I can define how to load classes before deploying EAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps to create module it should work

**Step-1**
In jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/com/company/gyani/main/

```
                      -module.xml
                      -my-custom-classes.jar


  Content of  module.xml


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.company.gyani">
    <resources>
      <resource-root path="my-custom-classes.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api"/>
         </dependencies>
      </module>
```

Step-2 Now IN my.ear/META-INF/

```
      -jboss-deployment-structure.xml
      -MANIFEST.MF
```

Content of MANIFEST.MF

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Dependencies: com.company.gyani
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use concept of module(s) provided by JBoss AS7.

Here you configure your classes/jars/property files as modules and these are loaded while starting JBoss at server scope and are accessible to any deployed application that carries a dependency on this module.

Read through [How to configure module](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7)